# Bazel Monorepo - How Rebuild and Publish only Changed Docker Images?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bazel, monorepo

## Objective

I have a monorepo setup with a growing number of services *services*. When I deploy the application I run a command and *every* service will be rebuilt and the final Docker images will be published.
But as the number of services grows the time it takes to rebuilt all of them gets longer and longer, although changes were made to only a few of them.

**Why does my setup rebuilt all Docker images although only a few have changed? My goal is to rebuilt and publish only the images that have actually *changed*.**

## Details

I am using Bazel to build my Docker images, thus in the root of my project there is one `BUILD` file which contains the target I run when I want to deploy. It is just a collection of `k8s_objects`, where every service is included:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_k8s//k8s:objects.bzl", "k8s_objects")
k8s_objects(
    name = "kubernetes_deployment",
    objects = [
        "//services/service1",
        "//services/service2",
        "//services/service3",
        "//services/service4",
        # ...
    ]
)
```

Likewise there is one `BUILD` file for every service which first creates a Typescript library from all the source files, then creates the Node.Js image and finally passes the image to the Kubernetes object:

```
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")
ts_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(
        include = ["**/*.ts"],
        exclude = ["**/*.spec.ts"]
    ),
    deps = [
      "//packages/package1",
      "//packages/package2",
      "//packages/package3",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
nodejs_image(
    name = "image",
    data = [":lib", "//:package.json"],
    entry_point = ":index.ts",
)

load("@k8s_deploy//:defaults.bzl", "k8s_deploy")
k8s_object(
  name = "service",
  template = ":service.yaml",
  kind = "deployment",
  cluster = "my-cluster"
  images = {
    "gcr.io/project/service:latest": ":image"
  },
)
```

Note that the Typescript lib also depends on some packages, which should also be accounted for when redeploying!

To deploy I run `bazel run :kubernetes_deployment.apply`

---

Initially one reason I decided to choose Bazel is because I thought it would handle building only changed services itself. But obviously this is either not the case or my setup is faulty in some way.

If you need more detailed insight into the project you can check it out here: https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas

Comment: Thanks for saying what is your goal, but I don't really see what is your question or problem. Can you clarify so that we can help without having to dig into the project?

Comment: you are right, I've updated the question

Comment: Did you find a solution or significant improvement for your problem?

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong back then. But Bazel usually caches the images and only rebuilds if a dependency has changed. If you need help you can look at this project: https://github.com/drakery3d/fullbazel

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Bazel repo itself does something similar:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ef0f8e61b5d3a139016c53bf04361a8e9a09e9ab/scripts/ci/ci.sh

The rough steps are:

- Calculate the list of files that has changed
- Use the file list and find their dependents (e.g. The bazel query`kind(.*_binary, rdeps(//..., set(file1.txt file2.txt)))` will find all binary targets which are dependents of either `file1.txt` or `file2.txt`)
- build/test the list of targets

You will need to adapt this script to your need (e.g. make sure it finds docker image targets)

To find out the kind of a target, you can use `bazel query //... --output label_kind`

EDIT:
A bit of warning for anyone who wants to go down this rabbit hole (especially if you absolutely do not want to miss tests in CI):

You need to think about:

- Deleted files / BUILD files (who depended on them)

  - Note that moved files == Deleted + Added as well
  - Also you cannot query reverse deps of files/BUILD that doesn't exist anymore!
- Modified BUILD files (To be safe, make sure all reverse deps of all targets in the BUILD are built)

I think there is a ton of complexity here going down this route (if even possible). It might be less erro-prone to rely on Bazel itself to figure out what changed, using remote caches & `--subcommands` to calculate which side-effects need to be performed.